# JDialog: Accessing Jframe while Jdialog is active

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a class that extends JDialog. When JDialog displays I click on its display button that initiates a Jframe but I am unable to access the JFrame until I close JDialog. how can I access Jframe in the presence of JDialog on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

> but I am unable to access the JFrame until I close JDialog.

This means you a using a modal JDialog.

You need to use a non-modal JDialog.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);
...
dialog.setVisible(true );
```

Or you can use the `setModal(false)` method before you make the dialog visible.